# firebase database not updating, even though successful response

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I have a chat app that I am building in ionic and firebase. I have a simple join channel function that takes the channel id, and adds the current user id to the list of member in the database. According to everything I am seeing it is working correctly, however whenever I go to the firebase console it is not showing the new item in the database. Here is the code I am using to add the item to the database when a user joins a chat channel...

```
joinChannel(type, user_id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(this.availableChannels[type] !== undefined) {
        console.log("joining channel: " + type);
        console.log('for user: ' + user_id);
        let update = {};
        update['/chat/members/' + type + '/' + user_id] = {active: true, joinedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP};
        this.afDB.database.ref().update(update).then(() => {
          console.log("updated /chat/members/" + type + "/" + user_id + " to");
          console.log({active: true, joinedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
          this.activeChannel = '/channels/' + type;
          resolve(true);
        })
      } else {
        reject("channel_not_found");
      }
    });
  }
```

Now, if I open up the developer console in chrome and click to join the channel I get this in the console...

```
joining channel: news
chat.ts:210 for user: [USERIDHERE]
chat.ts:214 updated /chat/members/news/[USERIDHERE] to
chat.ts:215 Object
              active: true
              joinedAt: Object
                .sv: "timestamp"
              __proto__: Object
              __proto__: Object
```

So the console shows that the database ran the update, however if I then log into my firebase console, there is no "news" item in the "chat/members" database. I have tried it with different channels, and always I get the same exact response from firebase, saying it updated the database, but in the firebase console that item remains blank.

Just in case it is needed the `this.afDB` variable is 
`public afDB: AngularFireDatabase`
in the constructor. I know the database is working because I can update things, send messages in chat channels and they appear in the firebase console, but for whatever reason, when a user joins a channel, I get the successful console log, but the database is not updating with the new information. I am really lost on this one and could really use some help.

Comment: Can you `console.log(update)` before you call `update()`? If that doesn't show anything helpful, can you reproduce this in a jsbin, so I can have a look?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Here is the console.log(update);
Object {
    /chat/members/news/TCJOEjaUUaUKt8UJjE0eTL0jYUm1:
      Object
        active: true
        joinedAt: Object
          .sv: "timestamp"
          __proto__:Object
        __proto__:Object
    __proto__:Object

I don't know how to recreate it in jsbin without giving out my firebase keys and such, hopefully one day this will be a public app, so I don't want to give out my firebase connection info.

Comment: OK, so that looks fine. In that case I don't immediately see what's going wrong. Can you reproduce in a jsbin so I can check?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you want to use a set instead of update

```html
this.afDB.database.ref('/chat/members/' + type + '/' + user_id)
.set({active: true, joinedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
```